# Simulate keydown event

Tags: smalltalk, keydown, visualworks

How can I simulate a key (ctrl) being hold down while some other code is executed? What would be the implementation of the following method?

```
self ctrlDownWhile: [self doSomething]
```

Comment: sorry - me stupid - comment removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to "trick" the input state, by changing its "ctrlDown" state.
The bad news is that it does not have a setter-method to access it (maybe only in my version), so you may have to get there with a trick:

```
ctrlDownWhile:aBlock
  "aBlock will see ctrlDown as true"

  |indexOfCtrlState|

  indexOfCtrlState := InputState allInstVarNames indexOf:'ctrlState'.

  InputState default instVarAt:indexOfCtrlState put:1.   
  aBlock  
    ensure: [
      InputState default instVarAt:indexOfCtrlState put:0.
    ].
```

an alternative is to create keyPress & keyRelease-events for the CTRL-key, and enqueue them into the WindowSensor, before and after the block's evaluation.

Comment: of course, you can add this as an extension to InputState; then no fiddling with instVar-offsets is req'd.

Comment: also, the above is not thread save, so better try the window-sensor alternative...